# C# Setting the Checked property of RadioButton in Usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, radio-button

In a WinForms application, I have a problem with setting a specific Radio Button's Checked property.
I have the following structure:

FlowLayoutPanel:

- UserControl:

  - TextBox
  - RadioButton
- UserControl:

  - TextBox
  - RadioButton

Etc.

When I generate User Controls, I have to pre-select a specific RadioButton of a single User Control. I can see the right RadioButton properties set when looking at the Control collection of the flowlayotpanel, but after showing the dialog window (it opens in a separate window), always the first UserControl's radio button is checked.

Control generation sample:

```
foreach (DataType someData in someDataList)
            {
                SampleUserControl suc = new SampleUserControl();
                suc.Parent = flowLayoutPanel1;
                if (someCondition) suc.IsChecked = true;
                suc.Init(someData);
                SampleUserControlCollection.Add(suc);
            }
```

User Control code sample:

```
public partial class SampleUserControl: UserControl
{
    public bool IsChecked = false;
    public SampleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        if (IsChecked) radioButton1.Checked = true;
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsChecked = radioButton1.Checked;

        if (IsChecked)
        {
            foreach (FonaKrasa fk in Parent.Controls)
            {
                if (!fk.Equals(this))
                {
                    if (fk.radioButton1.Checked) fk.radioButton1.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Radio buttons are "tricky." The checked property comes from the parent CheckBox class.  What you want to do instead is put the buttons in an instance of RadioButtonList and then set the RadioButtonList object's SelectedValue to set/get the selected button.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy I see that the RadioButtonList is a WebUI class. I have a winforms project :) (Should've started with that I suppose :) )

Comment: Yeah, that's an important tidbit, a lot of the class names are the same. :-)  I've suggested a minor edit to make it a bit more clear that this is related to WinForms (I'm mostly doing web and backend). Also, the "checked" tag is specifically for the html checked attribute.

Comment: Are you expecting them to behave as a group, across all UserControls?  If so, you will have to provide the logic, it will not happen by default.  Grouped RadioButtons must exist in the same container.  Perhaps you really want CheckBoxes, as it will be easier to implement the check/uncheck behaviors.